# getting line numbers to be deleted from an array

Tags: arrays, bash, sed

I am trying to remove certain lines from a huge file, getting line numbers to be deleted from an array. The file is at least 2GB in size and the my array size can be large as well. Can I do this without a for loop? What is fastest way? 
    Example:

```
input:
>1
>2
>3
>4
>5

declare -a A=(2 3 5);

output: 
>1
>4
```

Comment: Do you have an array already are do you have to build that too?

Comment: Are the files/array actually sorted or is this an artefact of the example ?

Comment: The above two comments boil down to "how are you creating the line-number array?"

Comment: I build a sorted array by parsing the input file once. I can delete lines in-place instead of storing the line numbers in an array. But instead of using sed command for each line, I wish to store the line numbers in an array, and delete all lines at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... getting line numbers to be deleted from an array.

If I understand it correct, your array `A` contains line numbers to be deleted from the input.

You could use `sed`:

```
sed $(printf "%dd;" "${A[@]}") inputfile
```

Use the `-i` option to modify the file in-place.

If the array is too large, consider using process substitution instead:

```
sed -f <(printf "%dd;" "${A[@]}") inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't to this in plain shell code. **sed** is the tool for editing/transforming files.

On-The-Fly create a sed-programm from your array and edit the INPUTFILE in-place (**-i**)

```
for line in ${A[@]}; do
    echo ${line}d
done| sed -i -f /dev/stdin $INPUTFILE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -vf` to get this array differential:

```
declare -a O=(1 2 3 4 5)
declare -a A=(2 3 5)

B=( $(grep -vf <(printf "%s\n" "${A[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${O[@]}")) )
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
declare -p B
declare -a B='([0]="1" [1]="4")'
printf "%s\n" "${B[@]}"
1
4
```

Comment: lol :) Probably you are not aware about output one gets from `declare -p B` What is shown here is the output of `declare -p B` command.

Comment: That was an epic fail @anubhava. Poor lad.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v n=2,3,5 'BEGIN{split(n,nn,",")} !(NR in nn) {print}' input >output
```

In the above, the list of lines to be deleted is provided as the variable `n`.  (I have it shown as a comma-separated format but other formats are possible.)  In the `BEGIN` block, this list is converted to an `awk` array called `nn`.  The remainder of the `awk` program simply prints all lines whose line number, `NR`, is not in the array of lines to be excluded, `nn`.

If `awk` implements its membership testing in a properly hashed fashion, the way python does it, then the above should be fast.  If not, not.